# Displaying 5 items at a time from an array of n items and again repeat from biginning in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am new to angularJs and i have a situation where i have to display 5 items from an array of multiple items. That is first display 1-5 items and then after some time say 2-3 seconds insert 6th item on top and remove the first item from the bottom. The array is displayed as 5th on top 4th next and so on. SO every time replace the top item with the next item and remove the bottom item. Also loop back from 1st item when the last item has been displayed. That is when the last item is displayed the next item should be the first item.

```
    $scope.activityFeedArray = function() {
    $scope.activityFeed[0] = $scope.actFeedArr[$scope.idx1];$scope.idx1=$scope.idx1+1;if($scope.idx1>=20){$scope.idx1=20-$scope.idx1};
    $scope.activityFeed[1] = $scope.actFeedArr[$scope.idx2];$scope.idx2=$scope.idx2+1;if($scope.idx2>=20){$scope.idx2=20-$scope.idx2};
    $scope.activityFeed[2] = $scope.actFeedArr[$scope.idx3];$scope.idx3=$scope.idx3+1;if($scope.idx3>=20){$scope.idx3=20-$scope.idx3};
    $scope.activityFeed[3] = $scope.actFeedArr[$scope.idx4];$scope.idx4=$scope.idx4+1;if($scope.idx4>=20){$scope.idx4=20-$scope.idx4};
    $scope.activityFeed[4] = $scope.actFeedArr[$scope.idx5];$scope.idx5=$scope.idx5+1;if($scope.idx5>=20){$scope.idx5=20-$scope.idx5};
};
 $interval(function() {$scope.activityFeedArray2();} , 1000);
```

Comment: no, my application needs it

Comment: Just implement a simple FILO queue and attach it as a model?

Comment: ok. Do you have any sample example. I'll try though.

Comment: Numerous ways to do this within an interval timer. Show us what you have tried

Comment: I have just taken the list and used ng-repeat to show the items . now i want to modify it so as to display as said above. i don't know how to iterate through array in above fashion tell me any one way.

Comment: The above code works fine but it too many $scope variables which is not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use $Interval function of angularjs like as follows :

```
    $interval(function() {activityFeedArray2();} , 1000);
    function activityFeedArray2() {
    $scope.activityFeed.shift();
    $scope.activityFeed.push(actFeedArr[counter]);
    counter=counter+1;
    if(counter>=actFeedArr.length) {
    counter = counter-actFeedArr.length;
    };
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that works fine.

```
app.controller("activityFeedCntrl",function($scope,$interval) {

$scope.activityFeed=[{id:1,msg:'a clicked'},{id:2,msg:'b clicked'},{id:3,msg:'c clicked'},{id:4,msg:'d clicked'},
{id:5,msg:'e clicked'}];
var counter = $scope.activityFeed.length;


var actFeedArr = [{id:1,msg:'a clicked'},{id:2,msg:'b clicked'},{id:3,msg:'c clicked'},{id:4,msg:'d clicked'},
{id:5,msg:'e clicked'},{id:6,msg:'f clicked'},{id:7,msg:'g clicked'},{id:8,msg:'h clicked'},{id:9,msg:'i clicked'},
{id:10,msg:'j clicked'},{id:11,msg:'k clicked'},{id:12,msg:'l clicked'},{id:13,msg:'m clicked'},{id:14,msg:'n clicked'},
{id:15,msg:'o clicked'},{id:16,msg:'p clicked'},{id:17,msg:'q clicked'},{id:18,msg:'r clicked'},{id:19,msg:'s clicked'},
{id:20,msg:'w clicked'}];


 $interval(function() {activityFeedArray2();} , 1000);
  function activityFeedArray2() {
    $scope.activityFeed.shift();
    $scope.activityFeed.push(actFeedArr[counter]);
    counter=counter+1;
    if(counter>=actFeedArr.length) {
        counter = counter-actFeedArr.length;
    };
    };
   });
```

In the html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="activityFeedApp">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>Activity Feed</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="activityFeedCntrl">
     <p>Activity Feed</p>
         <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="feed in activityFeed track by $index">
            <td ng-bind="feed.id"></td>
                <td ng-bind="feed.msg"></td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </div>
<script src="activityFeedApp.js" ></script>
<script src="activityFeedCntrl.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```